# Inner Join one table to another table multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Say I have three tables:

```
User Table
{
    UserId INT,
    Username NVARCHAR
    ...
}

Questions
{
    QuestionId INT
    QuestionText NVARCHAR
}

Answers
{
    AnswerId INT,
    QuestionId INT,
    UserId INT,
    Answer NVARCHAR
}
```

This structure is obviously overly simplified, but for the purpose of this example it should suffice.

What would be the best way to select users who have specific answers for specific questions, for instance - Assuming the tables are populated with the following data:

User Table

```
UserId              Username                ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   User1                   ... 
2                   User2                   ... 
3                   User3                   ...
4                   User4                   ...
5                   User5                   ...
6                   User6                   ...
7                   User7                   ...
8                   User8                   ...
9                   User9                   ...
10                  User10                  ...
...                 ...                     ...

etc
```

Questions Table

```
QuestionId              QuestionText
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                       What is your favorite color?
2                       What do you prefer cats or dogs?
3                       Do you prefer if it is too hot or too cold?
4                       What is your favorite season (Summer, Autumn (Fall), Winter, Spring)?
5                       How Old Are you?
...                     ...

etc
```

Answers Table

```
AnswerId                QuestionId              UserId          Answer
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                       1                       1               Red 
2                       1                       2               Red
3                       1                       3               Blue
4                       1                       4               Green
5                       1                       5               Black
6                       2                       6               Cats
7                       2                       1               Dogs
8                       3                       1               Too Cold
9                       4                       1               Spring
10                      5                       1               22
11                      2                       4               Dogs
12                      3                       4               Too Hot
13                      3                       3               Too Cold
14                      5                       6               46
15                      1                       8               Purple
```

If I wanted to select users who liked dogs and red or purple and under the age of 50 etc

Would the best (most efficient) way to do this be to have multiple joins from the user table to the answers table (one for each answer condition required)

For example:

If I were wanting to get the users who liked dogs and the color red I could use the following MSSQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
Users 
JOIN Answers As a1 
ON Users.UserId = a1.UserId 
JOIN Answers as a2 
ON Users.UserId = a2.UserId 
WHERE 
    (
        a1.QuestionId = 1 AND 
        a1.Answer = 'Red'
    ) AND 
    (
        a2.QuestionId = 2 AND 
        a2.Answer = 'Dogs'
    )
```

There could be numerous answer conditions.

Basically the question I am asking is what is the best way to write a query where you have conditions on multiple rows from the same table with the same columns...

Sorry if this is confusing, feel free to ask any questions I will try and answer them as best as I can...

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if this is badly written or phrased, its past midnight here and my clarity is quite lacking but I thought since it is of a reasonable time elsewhere someone maybe able to help. I have asked a similar question previously however as my understanding has grown I have wondered if that is still the right answer, perhaps multiple UNION selects are the answer... you can view the answer to the previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833056/sql-conditioning-multiple-rows-on-an-inner-joined-table

Comment: Ah.  It depends a lot (IME) on what performance is like.  Sometimes well-designed unions can be faster.

Comment: What would be a tipping point? If wanted to get users based on their answers to 10 or even 20 perhaps 100 questions? Which offers the best performance? Perhaps its not as simple as that?...

Comment: I did have a thought, perhaps you could tell me if it is correct or not... Would it be faster if I had a view (ex called vw_users) that had all the columns from the user table as well as a column for each of the questions (ex question1, question2) containing the users answer for each question, that way I could use a simple Where without the need for joins...

Comment: OK, at this point I'm speculating rather than giving a hard-and-fast rule, but unions would have more of an advantage if you were doing something like 'WHERE Table1.FieldA = something OR Table1.FieldB = somethingelse'.  You'd be able to use two separate query plans rather than it trying to come up with one overarching one.  But if it's always a matter of different values for the same one field, ORs will *probably* do about as well.  Unfortunately, this is a case where experimentation is probably necessary.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Ann for all your help :D. I will do some speed tests in the morning. I think that Its safe to say you have answered this question perfectly, I will mark yours as the correct answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I doubt that would give much of a performance advantage, unless it was an indexed view (which I don't necessarily recommend, not having a lot of experience with them.)  It might make programming simpler, though.

Comment: Yeah - Easier programming was the main reason behind the view comment. Thanks again, you have been most helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic query looks just fine.  As you get more elaborate, you would construct your WHERE clauses slightly differently depending on how your conditions need to be combined.

For example, in the example you provided, of either red or purple being acceptable answers, you could construct the WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE (a1.QuestionId = 1 AND (a1.Answer IN ('Red','Purple')) 
  AND (a2.QuestionId = 2 AND a2.Answer = 'Dogs')
```

It gets more complicated if only certain sets of answers are acceptable, so if 'Red' and 'Dogs' or 'Purple' and 'Cats' are acceptable, it would look more like this:

```
WHERE 
  (
          (a1.QuestionId = 1 AND a1.Answer = 'Red')
      AND (a2.QuestionId = 2 AND a2.Answer = 'Dogs')
  )
  OR
  (
          (a1.QuestionId = 1 AND a1.Answer = 'Purple')
      AND (a2.QuestionId = 2 AND a2.Answer = 'Cats')
  )
```

If your conditions get more complicated, you might want to read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).  While your conditions aren't dynamic, there's a lot of useful information there.

Finally, since it's easy to get confused with what question ID goes with what answers, particularly if they aren't nice, human-recognizable values, it can help to use CTEs to pre-select the answers:

```
WITH Colors
AS   (
    SELECT *
    FROM   Answers
    WHERE  QuestionID = 1
)
,    Animals
AS   (
    SELECT *
    FROM   Answers
    WHERE  QuestionID = 2
)
SELECT   *
FROM     Users 
   JOIN  Colors
       ON  Users.UserID = Colors.UserID
   JOIN  Animals
       ON  Users.UserID = Animals.UserID
WHERE   (
        Colors.Answer = 'Red'
    AND Animals.Answer = 'Dogs'
    )
    OR  (
        Colors.Answer = 'Purple'
    AND Animals.Answer = 'Cats'
    )
```

Comment: Thought this was the case (I know it works), but just because something works doesn't mean its the best or most efficient way to do something. Thanks for confirming this is the right way to go :D

Comment: I will mark yours as the answer in the morning (my time) if no other answers are provided I just want to see if anyone else has another approach and their reasoning behind it... thanks again for taking the time to answer. I am fairly sure you are right.

Comment: @Neaox  Oh, I see.  I assumed you were more of a beginner than it's now clear that you are.  You are right in your comment above:  sometimes unions can be faster. It depends (IME) on things like indexes, record size, and whether the OR'd conditions are a matter of different values for the same column, or unrelated columns.

Comment: +1 nice query; I have never seen two CTEs in a single statement and didn't know it was possible.

Answer (score 3):

There's also the option of using the [PIVOT operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

That's how the query you proposed above could be written:

```sql
select UserId, UserName
from (
  select
    u.UserId,
    u.UserName,
    case 
      when a.QuestionId = 1 then 'Color'
      when a.QuestionId = 2 then 'Animal'
      when a.QuestionId = 3 then 'Temperature'
      when a.QuestionId = 4 then 'Season'
      when a.QuestionId = 5 then 'Age'
    end as Question,
    a.Answer
  from Users u
  join Answers a on a.UserId = u.UserId
) as SourceTable
pivot (
  max(Answer)
  for Question in (
    [Color], 
    [Animal], 
    [Temperature], 
    [Season], 
    [Age])
) as pivotTable

where Animal = 'Dogs'
  and Color in ('red', 'purple')
  and Age < 50
```

Here's a link to test this online: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c960/23

Yes, the query looks cumbersome, but you could write it once and (assuming the questions don't change that often) just alter the `where` clause, which is pretty easy to write/read/understand/maintain (see the last three lines in the code block above).

**Update:**

For performance analysis, compare these two queries:

- Pivot version: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c960/23
- Ann L.'s CTE solution: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c960/26

(*after executing the queries, click the "**View Execution Plan**" link above the results to see what SQL does under the covers*)

What I recommend though is that you run these queries on a database of your own, where you may have already created appropriate indexes and where the volume of data could be enough to produce a relevant result.

I'm no SQL performance expert, but I have a hunch that [Ann L.'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12872726/390819) could be more efficient and scale better to large volumes of data. But that, again, it's just a hunch; if you can perform a test on your environment you could see the actual results.

Comment: Performance wise how would this stack up against the multi join method? Thanks for taking the time to answer I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Neaox I don't know for sure which query would be more efficient, but see if the update to my answer helps